# Using Google Analytics on a Javascript widget

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I've built Javascript widgets that have been installed on other websites.

How can I use google analytics on my widgets like I would use analytics on a web page to track the traffic?

FYI, the Javascript code for my widgets is created from PHP pages.

Answer (score 2):

It would likely be extremely unethical (and potentially illegal) to include tracking snippets in JS widgets that get installed on client sites. Unless they're iframe widgets, but I don't see anything about iframes in your post.

However, technically, there's no technical difference between implementing basic GA tracking on a site versus a JS widget. You just load the GA library, initialize it and send events. Any basic tracking manual would do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't see what ethics has to do with my request. I just want to track who uses my widgets.

Comment: Forget about ethics, in many countries (e.g. all of the EU) this would not even be legal without permission by both the website owner and the individuals being tracked.